# Подписки на события используя RxJs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Я создаю Observable и подписываюсь на него дважды, но при этом обновление приходит только для последнего подписавшегося:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

let observer;
let source = Observable.create(obs => observer = obs);
source.subscribe(m => console.log(`subscribe 1: ${m}`));
source.subscribe(m => console.log(`subscribe 2: ${m}`));
observer.next("hello!:)");
```

Я ожидал увидеть в консоли:

```
subscribe 1: hello!:)
subscribe 2: hello!:)
```

Но вместо этого получил только последнее сообщение:

```
subscribe 2: hello!:)
```

Можно ли сделать много подписок на одно событие?
Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: говорят надо Subject использовать вместо Observable.create

Comment: что интересно, если `next` ты будешь вызывать внутри `Observable.create` даже, с помощью setTimeout - то обе подписки сработают

Comment: Нашел пример с Subject -то что нужно. Проверил версию с вызовом next внутри, это действительно так, давольно странное/неочевидное поведение...

Comment: Коллега, пожалуйста прочитайте статью на мете излишнее форматирование, см: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/ и постарайтесь учесть в последующих правках. Понимаю, что вы стремитесь улучшить сайт, но возможно по незнанию вы делаете хуже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если добавить лог в callback:

```
let source = Observable.create(obs => {
    console.log('callback');
    observer = obs;
});
```

можно заметить, что он будет вызываться при каждом вызове `subscribe`.

Соответственно, при каждом вызове будет переписана глобальная переменная, в которой сохранится последнее значение.

---

Для решения можно воспользоваться методом [`share`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html)

```
let source = Rx.Observable.create(obs => observer = obs).share();
```

В этом случае один наблюдатель будет для всех подписок.

[Пример](https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?js=let%20observer%3B%0Alet%20source%20%3D%20Rx.Observable.create%28obs%20%3D%3E%20observer%20%3D%20obs%29.share%28%29%3B%0Asource.subscribe%28m%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%60subscribe%201%3A%20%24%7Bm%7D%60%29%29%3B%0Asource.subscribe%28m%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%60subscribe%202%3A%20%24%7Bm%7D%60%29%29%3B%0Aobserver.next%28%22hello%21%3A%29%22%29%3B)

---

Альтернативным решением может стать использование [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/subject.html) вместо `Observable.create`

```
let source = new Subject();
source.subscribe(m => console.log(`subscribe 1: ${m}`));
source.subscribe(m => console.log(`subscribe 2: ${m}`));
source.next("hello!:)");
```

[Пример](https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?js=let%20source%20%3D%20new%20Rx.Subject%28%29%3B%0Asource.subscribe%28m%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%60subscribe%201%3A%20%24%7Bm%7D%60%29%29%3B%0Asource.subscribe%28m%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%60subscribe%202%3A%20%24%7Bm%7D%60%29%29%3B%0Asource.next%28%22hello%21%3A%29%22%29%3B)